# Проблема работы setInterval

Tags: javascript

Есть слайдер, который прокручивается в заданный промежуток и при нажатии на него. Чтобы сдвиг при нажатии не совпадал со сдвигом через интервал, я прописал обнуление SetInterval при каждом клике и снова его установил. При этом при клике у меня выполняется сдвиг, обнуление интервала и его возобновление. Проблема в том, что после второго клика интервал будто сбивается, и уменьшается время сдвига, а примерно после клика 10-ого вовсе начинает дергать весь слайдер... Объясните пожалуйста в чем проблема, и подскажите как исправить.
P.S. просьба предлагать варианты только

```js
document.getElementById('polosa').onclick = together;

var left = 0;
var selfMove =setInterval (move,8000);
function move(){
 var polosa = document.getElementById('polosa');
 left = left - 200;
 if (left < -600){
  left=0;
 }
 polosa.style.left = left + 'px';
 
}
function zero(){
 
 clearInterval(selfMove);
    
}
function again(){
 var selfMove =setInterval (move,8000);
}
function together(){
 move();
 zero();
 again();
}
```

```css
body{
 margin:0;
}
#slider{
    width:600px;
 overflow:hidden;

}
#polosa{
 position:relative;
 display:flex;
 left:0;
 transition:left 1s ;
 
}
img{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<title>CRAFTBEER-SHOP</title>
<meta name="keywords" content=" ">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<header class="page-header">

</header>
<main class="page-main">
<div id="slider">
 <div id="polosa">
  <img src="kisa.jpg">
  <img src="sobaka.jpg">
  <img src="ptica.jpg">
  <img src="zmeya.jpg">
  <img src="fish.jpg">
  <img src="bear.jpg">
 </div>
</div>
</main>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

введите сюда код

на чистом JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка - объявление локальной переменной `selfMove` в функции `again`. Код в функции `again` не меняет значение глобальной переменной `selfMove`, `clearInterval` ничего не делает (кроме первого раза), и несколько таймеров начинают выстреливать вперемежку.

```js
document.getElementById('polosa').onclick = together;

var left = 0;
var selfMove = setInterval(move, 8000);

function move() {
  var polosa = document.getElementById('polosa');
  left = left - 200;
  if (left < -600) {
    left = 0;
  }
  polosa.style.left = left + 'px';
}

function again() {
  clearInterval(selfMove);
  /*var*/ selfMove = setInterval(move, 8000);
}

function together() {
  move();
  again();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#slider {
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#polosa {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 1s;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
  <header class="page-header">

  </header>
  <main class="page-main">
    <div id="slider">
      <div id="polosa">
        <img src="kisa.jpg">
        <img src="sobaka.jpg">
        <img src="ptica.jpg">
        <img src="zmeya.jpg">
        <img src="fish.jpg">
        <img src="bear.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
```

Comment: все отлично работает ! подскажите, если функции zero(), move(), again() объединить в одну, не будет ли внутри каких-либо ошибок, P.S. визуально все работает document.getElementById('polosa').onclick = move;

var left = 0;
var selfMove =setInterval (move,4000);
function move(){
 var polosa = document.getElementById('polosa');
 left = left - 200;
 if (left < -600){
  left=0;
 }
 polosa.style.left = left + 'px';
 clearInterval(selfMove);
    selfMove =setInterval (move,4000);
}

Comment: @СергейОрлов код в комментарии - это содержимое той "одной" функции? Напишите эту в вопросе, пожалуйста.